# Cuanto espacio puede ocupar un entero o dato

Tags: c++

Hola tengo entendido un entero ocupa: 4 bytes. Pero mi pregunta es si el entero es muy grande cuanto puede ocupar o 4 bytes es por cada numero entero. era esa mi duda. Y ya no es solamente por eso sino también para entender si otro tipo dato el tamaño se considera por unidad o por cada dato. es decir ejemplo un caracter "a" dos caracteres "aa" pesaran 2 bytes. Entonces pasara con enteros tambien "1" pesara 4 bytes "11" pesara 8 bytes ¿Es correcto?

Y esque esta es mi duda porque yo hecho este pequeño programa

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Tamaño de int es {0}"<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
    getch();
}
```

Y cuando pongo un numero largo como 2222222222

```
cout<<"Tamaño de int es {0}"<<sizeof(2222222222)<<endl;
```

Me da 4 bytes entonces no depende de tan grande sea el numero. alguien me puede explicar mejor como va esto del tamaño que ocupa en memoria cada dato?

y con los string pasa lo mismo que con los caracteres? ya que son cadenas de texto y con eso ya la respuesta me aclararía bastante mis dudas si es un string ¿como sería?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los números en se almacenan en formato binario. Así el número 10 se convierte en `1010` y el número 22 en `10110`.

En C++ los tipos no tienen un tamaño fijo, su tamaño es dependiente de la arquitectura del sistema. Eso sí, para una arquitectura determinada el tamaño de un tipo es fijo.

En el caso de `int`, en una aplicación para pc suele ocupar 32 bits. Si asumimos que este es tu caso y dado que 1 bit se emplea para indicar el signo del número tenemos que el rango de valores que admite el tipo `int` es de 2^31 a (-2^31)-1 o, dicho de otra forma de -2,147,483,648 a 2,147,483,647. Esto quiere decir que cualquier número dentro de este rango se almacenará en 4 bits independientemente del valor del mismo. Así el valor `1` y el valor `123456789` ocuparán ambos 32 bits (los dígitos de mayor peso que no estén en uso se inicializan con ceros).

En cualquier caso, C++ dispone de una serie de utilidades en la librería `limits` que te informan acerca del rango válido para cada tipo de dato. Así:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "rango de int:   " << std::numeric_limits<int>::min() << " a "
                                  << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n'
            << "rango de short: " << std::numeric_limits<short>::min() << " a "
                                  << std::numeric_limits<short>::max() << '\n'
            << "rango de char:  " << (int)std::numeric_limits<char>::min() << " a "
                                  << (int)std::numeric_limits<char>::max() << '\n';
}
```

Su salida:

```
rango de int:   -2147483648 a 2147483647
rango de short: -32768 a 32767
rango de char:  -128 a 127
```

Si te excedes en la capacidad de uno de los tipos se provoca un efecto conocido como desbordamiento (*overflow*). En este caso se activa un flag específico en el procesador y el número pierde valores:

```
int main()
{
  int valor = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  std::cout << valor << '\n' << valor + 1;
}
```

Su salida:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

Como ves, el número ha dado de repente la vuelta. Pasa de un número positivo a uno negativo esto es porque:

```
  0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 -> 2147483647
+                                       1
  ---------------------------------------
  1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 -> -2147483648
  ^
  Este es el bit de signo
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  int valor = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  std::cout << valor << '\n' << valor + valor;
}
```

Salida:

```
2147483647
-2
```

Explicación a este segundo caso

```
  0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 -> 2147483647
+ 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 -> 2147483647
  ---------------------------------------
1 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 -> -2
^                                             ^
Este dígito se pierde                         Los números negativos se almacenan en complemento a 2
```

Así, cualquier suma de dos enteros siempre va a dar un resultado, aunque este sea incorrecto (para eso está el flag de desbordamiento).

¿Qué sucede en el caso de las cadenas de caracteres?

Las cadenas de caracteres no son un tipo nativo. No ocupan un número regular de bytes ya que depende del tamaño del texto a almacenar.

Aquí habría que distinguir entre arreglo de caracteres y las clases de cadenas (`std::string`, `std::wstring`, ...):

- En el caso de los arreglos de caracteres has de tener presente que en algún momento has indicado el tamaño máximo. En este caso, si intentas escribir más allá del tamaño definido (recuerda que los índices empiezan a contar en 0), lo que conseguirás es escribir en memoria que no pertenece al arreglo. Esto suele desembocar en un mal funcionamiento del programa o incluso en un casque si el Sistema Operativo se da cuenta.

  ```
  char cadena[10];
  cadena[10] = '0'; // Error estás escribiendo fuera del arreglo
  ```
- En el caso de las clases de cadenas has de saber que son las propias clases las que se encargan de gestionar la memoria para la cadena. Ellas solitas son capaces de adaptar el tamaño del buffer para que entre el texto que intentes almacenar. Este tipo de elementos también tiene un tamaño máximo que puede estar en torno a los 2^32 o 2^64 caracteres (eso si no te quedas sin memoria antes).

Comment: y con los string pasa lo mismo que con los caracteres? ya que son cadenas de texto y con eso ya la respuesta me aclararía bastante mis dudas si es un string ¿como sería? - actualice el post

Answer (score 4):

Los caracteres se guardan de a un byte por carácter. Con los números no pasa los mismos.

Los números se guardan comprimidos como binarios. Un numero binario es un numero posicional donde cada posición con un uno indica que esa posición esta "prendida" y para calcular su valor se hace 2^posición. (arrancando desde la posición 0).

Como ejemplo:

Para guardar 456. Primero lo convertimos a binario.

```
                           256 + 0 + 64 + 32 + 0 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 0
                            1    0   1     1   0   0   1   0   0
```

Ahora tienes un numero de 9 bits, y tienes que llenar los restantes 23 con 0.

Así que el valor que se guarda es:

```
         00000000 00000000 00000001 01100100
```

Tu duda es común, cuando piensas los números como cadenas, pero los procesadores suelen guardar los números en otro formato distinto, para ahorrar espacio y aprovechar ventajas computacionales con los bits (multiplicar por dos es hacer por ejemplo un corrimiento de bits a izquierda, dividir a derecha).

Comment: y con los string pasa lo mismo que con los caracteres? ya que son cadenas de texto y con eso ya la respuesta me aclararía bastante mis dudas si es un string ¿como sería?

Comment: un strings es una cadena de caracteres, cada caracter ocupa un byte. o sea que un string ocupa un byte por caracter.

Comment: a  vale 9 bits porque la posicion del binario 1 esta en 9 por lo que es un numero de 9 bits.¿creo?

Comment: Ah ya entendi tu comentario. No, el numero siempe ocupa la misma cantidad de bytes, lo que pasa es q en este caso te alcanza con los primeros 9 bits para representarlo, y todo el resto van a quedar en cero. Pero los tamaños son fijos.

Comment: Y los enteros suelen ocupar 4 bytes. o 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Los enteros siempre van a pesar los 4 bytes(32 bits). 
Cuándo declaras un entero se le asigna un espacio de memoria de 32 bits,  estos bits pueden o no ser usados en su totalidad.
Cómo los números se guardan en binario si tú guardas un uno tendrías:
00000000000000000000000000000001
Y si tú guardas un 11 sería:
00000000000000000000000000001011.

En caso de los caracteres sí tendrás un byte por cada carácter que tengas. Ya que los caracteres se representan en 8 bits por lo tanto también se guardan en unos unos ceros. 
Para más información puedes consultar la tabla ascii la cual te dice el valor número que la corresponde a una letra.

Comment: La afirmación de que **siempre** van a pesar 4 bytes es falsa. En arquitecturas de 16 bits el tipo `int` ocupará sólo 2 bytes

Comment: Pero 16 bits hoy en día?

Comment: Te sorprenderías de la cantidad de equipos antiguos que todavía están en uso. De todas formas fue solo un ejemplo. Te pongo otro más actual. Si tu recoges el tamaño de un vector en un `unsigned int`, en 64 bits puedes tener problemas. La STL usa `size_t` que en 64 bits ocupa 8 bytes frente a los 4 de `unsigned int`

Comment: Y si ese ejemplo no te gusta, lo mismo pasaría si sustituyes `size_t` por `unsigned long`

Comment: Y ya el último ejemplo. Tienes dos aplicaciones, una de 32 bits y otra de 64. El código fuente es exactamente el mismo. Los archivos binarios que genera una de ellas no pueden ser abiertos por la otra. ¿motivo? Usar el tipo `long` para uno de los datos que se guardan en el fichero. La de 32 bits usa 4 bytes y la de 64, 8 bytes y esto hace que los registros se desalineen.